# Manually edit virtual hosts with MAMP pro?

Tags: mamp-pro

I have used MAMP Pro to handle my virtual hosts entries. I now need to edit these as code.  I can see them at the file path below, but editing them doesn't seem to affect my web server. When I restart MAMP my changes are lost.

/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf

I can go File / Edit template / Apache / and chose httpd.conf but I cant see any of the virtual hosts that I set up with MAMP Pro.

How can I edit the virtual hosts as code so that the changes take effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Hosts tab in the MAMP Pro UI you have a field for "Additional parameters for ;"

Comment: mine have stopped working and can't start apache with an extra parameters. Do you happen yo know what format we need to add them as? i.e. WP_ENV = dev or WP_ENV "dev"?